# Vaadin Responsive layout not working

Tags: vaadin7

Im using new Version of `Vaadin which is 7.4.5+`

```
    package com.example.projnew;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.util.PropertysetItem;
import com.vaadin.server.Responsive;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.CssLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Form;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("projnew")
public class ProjnewUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ProjnewUI.class)

public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    CssLayout layout = new CssLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    layout.setStyleName("flexwrap");
    setContent(layout);
    Responsive.makeResponsive(layout);

    Label title = new Label("Space is big, Really big");
    title.addStyleName("title");
    layout.addComponent(title);

    Label description = new Label("This is a "
            + "long description of the image shown "
            + "on the right or below, depending on the "
            + "screen width. The text here could continue long.");
    description.addStyleName("itembox");
    description.setSizeUndefined();
    layout.addComponent(description);
}

}
```

My style

```
    @import "addons.scss";
@import "projnew.scss";

/* This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes. */
/* The actual styles should be defined in projnew.scss */
.projnew {
  @include addons;
  @include projnew;

  .flexwrap {
    background: black;

    &[width-range~="0-300px"] {
        background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my design cant respond to the width I supposed to..
I tried many examples at vaadin but it doesnt work also.
And why is it that some examples they use `com.vaadin.addon.responsive.Responsive` but in my Vaadin version which is already in the utility and I imported `com.vaadin.server.Responsive`

What I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late and you probably already solved it, but...

The reason why they use `com.vaadin.addon.responsive.Responsive` is because `Responsive` used to be an extension and later they integrated it in the framework.

Are you sure the component is getting the width-range attribute? Open your browser's inspector, look at the component and see if it's there. If it is, then you have an issue with your CSS. If it isn't, or it is somewhere else, be sure you have applied it to the proper element.